# How to link XSLT from another server on XML

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

In my XML file I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='utf-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://anotherServerLocation/file.xslt" ?>
```

And I get:

> XML-25026: Stylesheet URL references an untrusted server.

If I add XSLT file inside application and call only file.xslt, it works.

I also can open the XSLT file with my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't.**

Your particular [error message](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_ermg_xml.htm#ADXDK99944) can be found in the list of [XSQL Server Pages Error Messages](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_ermg_xml.htm#ADXDK99944) and is fairly self-explanatory.  You cannot load an XSLT file from a remote URL.  The reason is due to XSS security concerns.   You'll have to serve it from the same origin as the XML file.